# bootstrap gradient background error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to put the gradient to background,but sends me error,help please, leave the codes:
please,i want that the entire screen be the gradient,but i dont now how,i try with multiple things but nothing,and i want that the text be in the middle of the webpage,thanks

```css
.header{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* W3C */
  height: 50em;
  width: 100%;      
}
#letraheader{
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#letraheaerdos{
  font-family: 'Grand Hotel', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>personal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
   <!-- fuentes -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Grand+Hotel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- fuentes final -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
 
      <header class="container-fluid header">
           
     <h1 class="col-xs-12" id="letraheader">HOLA</h1>
        <h2 class="col-xs-12" id="letraheaerdos"><em>Bienvenidos a mi pagina de presentacion</em></h2>
      </header>
 
  
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```css
body{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* W3C */

  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
 
  
}
#letraheader{
font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  font-size: 5em;
color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;

  vertical-align: middle;
  
}
#letraheaerdos{
font-family: 'Grand Hotel', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
color: aliceblue;
 text-align: center;
}
.header{
 min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>personal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
   <!-- fuentes -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Grand+Hotel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- fuentes final -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
   
        
        
        
<body>
 
      <header class="container-fluid header">
           
     <h1 class="col-xs-12" id="letraheader">HOLA</h1>
        <h2 class="col-xs-12" id="letraheaerdos"><em>Bienvenidos a mi pagina de presentacion</em></h2>
      </header>
 
 
    

  
   
  
     
   
  
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the gradient fill the entire screen, move the gradient CSS to the `body` instead of the `.header`, e.g.

```
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* IE10 */
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #AA076B 10%, #61045F 90%); /* W3C */
}
```